# How to tilt ellipse in ellipse series by some angle

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

Hi I am using LightningChartJs and would like to tilt the ellipse at 45 degrees.Please let me know what method I can use along with the add method of the ellipse series.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently LightningChart JS doesn't have support for rotating an [`EllipseFigure`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/classes/ellipsefigure.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply wil this be supported in version two?

Comment: Right now it's not planned for version 2.0 release. We will be implementing that in version release after 2.0, current target is 2.1.